# What happens when a dielectric-ball is placed in the uniform electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

Let the space filled with a dielectric having a dielectric constant $\varepsilon_1$, there are a uniform electric filed $\textbf{E}_1$ in the space. We set a dielectric-ball in this space.

My text has the following 【Practice problems】and 【Answer of Practice problems】 (originally written in Japanese)(See ref.1). I read them but them but, I'm not sure of the points described in 【My Questions】, below.

**【My Questions】**

> - Can I understand the $\textbf{P}$ of the【Answer of Practice problems】 is the polarization of Dielectric-ball? If so, **Is the vacuum polarized** in the setting of the (3) of 【Practice problems】?
> - It seems that **the answer assumed the $\textbf{E}$ is uniform** in the Dielectric-ball. But, How can I justify this?

**【Practice problems】**:
Rough translation of the Practice problems, quoted from (ref.1) with minor modification.

> Let the space filled with a dielectric having a dielectric constant $\varepsilon_1$, there are a uniform electric filed $\textbf{E}_1$ in the space. We set a dielectric-ball in this space.  The dielectric constant and the radius of spherical dielectric is $\varepsilon_2$ and a respectively.
>
> - (1). Then, find the electric field inside of the dielectric-ball.
> - (2). Draw the [Electric flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_flux)-lines schematically for the case of $\varepsilon_2\ >\varepsilon_1 $ and, $\varepsilon_2 <\varepsilon_1 $ .
> - (3). In particular, what happens if the dielectric-ball is a void ? (That means, the dielectric-ball is the vacuum therefore, $\varepsilon_2=\varepsilon_0$)
>
> Here, we can suppose the [electric polarizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizability) is represented as follows in our case.
>   $$\chi=\ {\varepsilon_2/\varepsilon}_1\ -\ 1\tag{Q1-1}$$
>   The length of vector are represented by $|\ |$ for example, 
>   $$E\ =\ |\textbf{E}|\ ,\ P=|\textbf{P}|\tag{Q1-2}$$
>
> [image] 
>   **Fig. 1**: Dielectric-ball

**【Answer of Practice problems】**:
Rough translation of the answer of the 【Practice problems】, quoted from  (ref.1)  with minor modification.

> The ring shape [area-element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_element#Area_element_of_a_surface) $dS$ on the surface of the ball, shown in the figure is expressed as follows. 
>   $$dS=2\pi a^{2}sin\theta d\theta \tag{A 1-1}$$
>   We denote $\textbf{P}$ as the dielectric polarization, then, the polarization charge generated in $dS$ is
>   $$P\cos\theta dS=2P\pi a^2\ (\cos\theta)(\sin\theta)d\theta \tag{A 1-2}$$
>
> The electric field created by this polarization electrification at the center of the sphere is expressed by Coulomb's law as follows.
>   $$dE_0=\left(\frac{Pcos\theta dS}{4\pi\varepsilon_0a^2}\right)cos\theta\ =\frac{P\left(cos^2\theta\right)\ (sin\theta)d\theta}{2\varepsilon_0}\ \tag{A 1-3}$$
>   
>   Sum up the $dE_0$ over the entire spherical surface, the electric field at the origin O is obtained. This is obtained by integrating the above equation from 0 to π with respect to as follows.
>   $$E_0\ =\ \frac{\textbf{P}}{2\varepsilon_0}\ \int_{0}^{\pi}{\left(cos^2\theta\right)\ (sin\theta)d\theta\ }\ =\frac{\textbf{P}}{3\varepsilon_0} \tag{A 1-4}$$
>   
>   From the supposition (see (Q1-1)), the electric polarizability is represented as follows in our case,
>   $$\chi=\ {\varepsilon_2/\varepsilon}_1\ -\ 1\tag{A 1-5}$$
>   
>   The $\textbf{P}$ satisfies 
>   $$\mathbf{P}=\ \varepsilon_0\left({\varepsilon_2/\varepsilon}_1\ -\ 1\right)\textbf{E}\tag{A 1-6}$$
>   
>   On the other hand, the sign of the surface polarization charge is opposite to that of the external electric field. Therefore, the electric field $\textbf{E}$ at the $\textbf{O}$ is
>   $$\textbf{E}=\textbf{E}_1-\textbf{E}_0=\textbf{E}_1-\frac{\textbf{P}}{3\varepsilon_0}\tag{A 1-7}$$
>   
>  
>   Therefore, 
>   $$\textbf{E}=\textbf{E}_1-\frac{\textbf{P}}{3\varepsilon_0}\ =\textbf{E}_1+\ \frac{1}{3}\left(\ 1-{\varepsilon_2/\varepsilon}_1\ \right)\textbf{E} \tag{A 1-8}$$
>   
>   we get the answer of (1) is as follows.
>   $$\textbf{E}=\frac{\mathbf{3}}{\left(\ 1+{\varepsilon_2/\varepsilon}_1\ \right)}\textbf{E}_\mathbf{1}\tag{A 1-9 }$$
>   Therefore, the answer of (2) as shown in Fig.2.
>    [image] 
>   **Fig**.2 The answer of (2).
>   
>   If the dielectric-ball is a void, such that
>   $$\varepsilon_2=\varepsilon_0 \tag{A 1-10}$$
>   Then, the answer of (3) is as follows.
>   $$\textbf{E}=\frac{\mathbf{3}\varepsilon_s}{\left(\ 2\varepsilon_s\ +\ 1\ \right)}\textbf{E}_\mathbf{1}\tag{A 1-11}$$ 
>   Here,
>   $$\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon_0\tag{A 1-12}$$
>   ■

**【Reference】**
 (ref.1) Hitoshi Ookubo, et.al.;" [電気磁気学 (Electromagnetism)](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E9%9B%BB%E6%B0%97%E7%A3%81%E6%B0%97%E5%AD%A6-%E5%A4%A7%E4%B9%85%E4%BF%9D-%E4%BB%81/dp/4785611871)"  Shou-Ko-Do,Tokyo (1993/10).P.P.66-67(Written in Japanese)

**P.S.** I'm not very good at English, so I'm sorry if I have some impolite or unclear expressions. I welcome any corrections and English review. (You can edit my question and description to improve them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with the second question and then the first:

1. If I remember correctly, the electric field in this particular scenario in the dielectric ball does come out to be uniform, but I have no trivial way to explain why that is so. Instead, I  suggest you solve Laplace's equation in and out of the sphere with the correct boundary conditions (this is how I solved it at the time...).
2. The vacuum isn't polarized, $P$ is the polarization of the ball, not the vacuum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  For 2, my textbook use similar manner even when the dielectric ball is the vacant. 
At that time, I think it is strange to use this P.　(See the (3) of 【Practice problems】)
How can we justify it?

Comment: For 1. 
Is this an analogy to Method of image charges?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges

Comment: @BlueVarious , for 1: well, this method is allowed due to the uniqueness theorem of the equation, but it isn't an analogy - you really need to solve it. 2. For vacuum, $\epsilon = \epsilon_0 , \chi =0 $ so it isn't polarized. Notice, however, that they define $\chi$ differently, so they pretend the outside is "vacuum" and the inside has a different permitivity compared to it. Meaning although the surface charge will actually rise from the surroundings, they solve the problem in a different way, pretending they come from the relative permitivity of the ball.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Oops!! Assuming that there is polarization, but it is zero after all?